# How to create a persistent list of modified SObjects for later sync to 3rd party system?

Tags: list

Over the course of a 24 hour period, I need to keep some sort of persistent list of contacts that have been updated under certain conditions.  I'll populate the list with a trigger that evaluates the contact changes and, if appropriate, includes the contact in the persistent list.  The list will then be processed in the middle of the night to sync up information with a 3rd party system.  The list will then be deleted or emptied so the next cycle can start fresh.

So the question is, is there a best practice for doing this kind of thing? I had first thought of just using a custom object, but that seems heavier weight than is needed.  I'm new to apex and have been reading up on 'static' objects, but these seem to behave differently than static variables in other languages.

Any suggestions/best practices for Salesforce/Apex?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd go with the custom object for this honestly.

Comment: In case the "updated under certain conditions" is something quite simple, you should see if the history table created by the platform when you turn on [Tracking Field History](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history.htm&language=en_US) could be the data source for your nightly sync up.

Comment: any reason you can't add a custom checkbox field to contact that the trigger updates?  And then have the job that processes the contact records uncheck them when its complete with its processing?

Comment: Confused. Why not just use a batch process querying for the records with a last modified date = LAST_N_DAYS:1 and then evaluate the scope in the execute method? What does maintaining a separate object with a list of those records get you?

Comment: If the batch runs at slightly different times from one day to the next then LAST_N_DAYS:1 has slightly different meaning for each run. The extra object or flag gets you a guaranteed "I have / have not processed this record".